# how to avoid system modify time stam, NSDate, objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimezone

Below is the string of time stamp which is returned by some server

```
dateFromServer = 2013-07-08 16:45:03Z
```

I am doing the following to convert it to an NSDate

```
     NSDateFormatter *format         =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                        [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];


    NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [format setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];

   dateFromServer                  =   [dateFromServer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];

   NSDate      *oldTime            =   [format dateFromString:dateFromServer];
```

and I am getting

```
oldTime is 2013-07-08 20:45:03 +0000
```

It looks like +4 is added to the original time stamp

Why does it do that, and how do I avoid this situation?

Comment: This is a difference in time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not know objective C but I do know the point of the problem. I'll try to guess along with the syntax.

When you receive `2013-07-08 16:45:03Z` the Z means UTC, or GMT+/-0000.

You are parsing it as a local timezone, or GMT-0400.

You then reemit it as reconverted into UTC with a 4 hour overcompensation.

To fix this, change:

```
NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

to

```
NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Honestly, I'm not sure if you need to do any wrapping for the `0` to act as an `NSInteger` but that's what you need.

You may have been intermittently missing this bug as a failure to determine time would have fallen back to the desired effect.

Out of curiosity, could someone comment as to whether my code is at least partially correct?

Comment: super close syntax. Just remove the `i` in front of `timeZoneForSeconds...` and remove your parenthesizes, so: `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`

Answer (score 3):

The `NSDate` object doesn't preserve the timezone. Instead, when printing the date (I assume through a `NSLog(@"%@", oldTime);`) it will use the current timezone. If your system is set to GMT (+0000) then it will print like that.

The date is still correct, and if you force it to print with the correct time zone it will be correct.